# Tracking the progress of WMI Defrag Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, api, winapi, wmi

I am looking at something like this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2901324/Re-the-result-of-DefragAnalysis-method-in-csharp.aspx

Which is perfect for my needs. I ran it as a thread and everything is working good.
The Only thing i wanted was being able to track the progress.

For example: 50% Analyzed or something like that.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The WMI doesn't provide any mechanism to monitor the progress of the [`defrag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, as workaround you can implement your own defrag method using the [WinAPi functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) related to this task.